# How to Add GIf image as layer on view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am working on a project in which A video is recorded.
When recording is finished, I play video using AVPlayer adding layer to view.
 Now I want a gif image as adding layer to that view.

I successfully Add gif image as layer, but image is not animated. It is like a static image.
I use [Library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) for GIF image.

My code is below

```
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.urlstring];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
videoLayer.frame = self.preview_view.bounds;
videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

[self.preview_view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];


NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"02" withExtension:@"gif"];

CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
layer.frame = self.img_gif.bounds;
layer.contents = (id) [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]].CGImage;
[self.preview_view.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Please help me with it

Thank you

Comment: I believe you have to use startAnimating for it to show the image animating.

Comment: But startanimating is used with UIimageview . I use CALayer to add image as layer on view

Comment: What if you make layer.contents equal to a UIImageView which contains the gif and you animate the gif?

Comment: Still same result. Image is not animating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully done it. I added my GIF image to layer.

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *)createGIFAnimation:(NSData *)data{

    CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)(data), nil);
    int frameCount =(int) CGImageSourceGetCount(src);

    // Total loop time
    float time = 0;

    // Arrays
    NSMutableArray *framesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *tempTimesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){

        // Frame default duration
        float frameDuration = 0.1f;

        // Frame duration
        CFDictionaryRef cfFrameProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(src,i,nil);
        NSDictionary *frameProperties = (__bridge NSDictionary*)cfFrameProperties;
        NSDictionary *gifProperties = frameProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

        // Use kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime or kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime
        NSNumber *delayTimeUnclampedProp = gifProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime];
        if(delayTimeUnclampedProp) {
            frameDuration = [delayTimeUnclampedProp floatValue];
        } else {
            NSNumber *delayTimeProp = gifProperties[(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];
            if(delayTimeProp) {
                frameDuration = [delayTimeProp floatValue];
            }
        }

        // Make sure its not too small
        if (frameDuration < 0.011f){
            frameDuration = 0.100f;
        }

        [tempTimesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:frameDuration]];

        // Release
        CFRelease(cfFrameProperties);

        // Add frame to array of frames
        CGImageRef frame = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, nil);
        [framesArray addObject:(__bridge id)(frame)];

        // Compile total loop time
        time = time + frameDuration;
    }

    NSMutableArray *timesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    float base = 0;
    for (NSNumber* duration in tempTimesArray){
        //duration = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(duration.floatValue/time) + base];
        base = base + (duration.floatValue/time);
        [timesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:base]];
    }

    // Create animation
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];

    animation.duration = time;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.values = framesArray;
    animation.keyTimes = timesArray;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;

    return animation;
}
```

To add image in layer of view write below code

```
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.frame = self.preview_view.bounds;

   CAKeyframeAnimation *animation =  [self createGIFAnimation:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
    ["YOUR VIEW".layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Comment: Do you have a swift example for this?

Comment: @yaali I don't have swift example.

Comment: I followed the above procedure and added the layer to my view's sublayer but couldn't see the gif image in my screen :( I double checked the output of animation, i am getting values. I am able to get the CAkeyframeAnimation but not able to render it in view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your image view.

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

layer.contents = (id) [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]].CGImage;
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"02" withExtension:@"gif"];
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:layer];
[layer setNeedsDisplay];

[self.view addSubview: animateImageView];
```

Comment: By adding this thing, It is successfully working. What I want is to add image as a layer of view so after I can merge both layers and make a common video